# How to remove gap between the list items in horizontal FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

In React Native's FlatList, create a list in the horizontal direction, and in the Container, create a View with a width of 50 or less, in addition to the FlatList.
Then, if the width of the ListItem is set to 59 or less, a gap is created between the list items.
No library is used. How can I eliminate this gap?

If in doubt, paste the following code into App.js.
The version of React Native is 0.72.7.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <View style={{height: 500, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
        renderItem={() => (
          <View style={{height: 100, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified few things in your code. I have added two views with `position` property, so that it will looks stick to Header & Footer. And no gap also. Hope will help

```
return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ height: 100, width: 50, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
        )}
      />

      <View style={{ height: 500, width: 50, backgroundColor: "blue", position: "absolute", left: 0 }} />
      <View style={{ height: 500, width: 50, backgroundColor: "cyan", position: "absolute", right: 0 }} />
    </View>
  );
```

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange and it is only on `Android` when both width are 50! Below would fix it.

**Add a placeHolder as `ListHeaderComponent` and set other View to `position: "absolute"`**

```js
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ height: 50, width: 50,}} />}

            horizontal
            data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={{ height: 100, width: 51, backgroundColor: "red" }}/>
            )}
          />

          <View style={{ height: 500, width: 50, backgroundColor: "blue", position: "absolute" }} />
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Thanks,  but I need sticky header and footer.

Comment: No Problem! FlatList has a `stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}` which inherits from scrollView but unfortunately does not work in horizontal mode. Other solution would be: adding a placeHolderView with same width to `ListHeaderComponent`  and placing the other after FlatList with `position:'absolute', left : 0`

Comment: Thanks, but I also need sticky Footer.